# Trouble in logic with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an online shop of watches. It has a search filter. One criterium of filtering is the material of body of watches. There are lots of unique values of it. For instance: "steel", "steel with gold", "steel with gold plating".

I tried to filter watches by creating an sql LIKE request to filter watches with steel body, gold body. But when searching for watches with golden body it also gives me steel watches with gold plating because it consists the word "gold".

Can you suggest a good solution to solve this problem?

So far I tried this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `watches` WHERE `material` LIKE "%gold%"
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use sphinx_search, create a table called filters. Insert all the features/filters into this table and map those to their respective watch_ids. Index this table and you have all the control now. If im being unclear, google sphinx_search, it solves all of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this I would create a table called "Material" and add a record for each material available, then store the material id in the watches table instead of the words. (There are a number of reasons this is better.)

Material Table:

```
id - Material
1 - Gold
2 - Gold Plated
3 - Silver
4 - Steel with Gold
```

Then in your search you would allow the user to select the materials they are interested in and your sql would look something like this:

```
Select * from Watches where Material IN (1,4);
```

This would bring up an watch that is made of Gold or Steel with Gold.  And your searches will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$criterium = "gold";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM watches WHERE material = '$criterium'");
```

It should solve your problem. Also check SQL LIKE condition for further queries

Comment: That won't work the way you have it. `LIKE` requires wildcards (`%` signs) in the string, otherwise it's just the same as using equals. Also, `LIKE` queries are extremely slow -- use them with caution; if your DB is large, you'll need an alternative solution.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know they were slow. What I understood, he needs to compare the exact word, so an equals(=) should works fine.